# Is it possible to use python mock for complex multidimensional dictionary input?

Tags: python, python-mock

I have started reading about the [mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/getting-started.html) library but haven't quite figure out how to use it as an input value to test my sync function.

My sync function takes a multidimensional dictionary from external source and then parse it and translate to various Django database records

I have bravely tried:

```
sync(MagicMock())
```

But surely expected to fail bluntly due to the type of the values that mock returns.

So I think I better manually set some return values, I have tried the following experiment:

```
>>> m = MagicMock()
>>> m['categories'] = [1,2,3]
>>> m['categories'].__class__
<class 'mock.MagicMock'>
>>> m['categories'][0]
<MagicMock name='mock.__getitem__().__getitem__()' id='4557691280'>
```

Also tried the return_value

```
>>> m = MagicMock()
>>> m['categories'].return_value = [1,2]
>>> m['categories']
<MagicMock name='mock.__getitem__()' id='4557733712'>
```

But the code inside the sync function is expecting integer values from the dictionary...

Comment: You say "My sync function takes a multidimensional dictionary" and later say "But the sync function is expecting integer values".  What exactly (provide an example) do you want mock to return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with [patch.dict](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#patch-dict):

```
from mock import patch

m = dict()

with patch.dict(m, {'categories': [1, 2, 3]}):
    print(m['categories'])

print(m)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [PropertyMock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html#mock.PropertyMock):

```
>>> m = MagicMock()
>>> p = PropertyMock(return_value=3)
>>> type(m).foo = p
>>> m.foo
3
```